# Using Microsoft VS2010 Publish Fails to deploy .json files

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, publishing-site

Anyone know what would make vs2010 not deploy .json files when doing a publish? All the other files (.js,.html, etc.) publish, but the .json files just to not move.

I don't think I've done anything special that would prevent that so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the file choose "properties" and set "content" as for the "Build Action"
.JSON is not known to VS2010 web application file types
You can change the behavior of vS2010 by [editing the registry](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your choosing to only deploy nessicary files, visual studio may not have any hard links to the json files, and thusly does not include them in the deploy. You can choose to deploy all files in Package/Publish settings. Or just ftp the json files manually.